# can Julia be used in programming for the game engine Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, julia

I am working on a research project and I want to know if I can use Julia for the game engine unity. If so,  How would it access the libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can only use **C#** and/or **UnityScript** (a kind of javascript for Unity).

In the past another language; Boo was also an option, but the support was removed.

Source: [Unity scripting languages and you](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/03/documentation-unity-scripting-languages-and-you/)

Comment: I don't know very much about this, so I'll just add a comment - but generally julia isn't ideal for purposes such as games, since the language is automatically garbage collected. Every once in an unpredictable while, the garbage collector will run, and the running operation will take a lot longer than usual. That's not a problem in technical computing, but not ideal for games.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard That's is a good observation, but at the end I think that the answer is 'it depends'. C# also have a garbage collector and you can have spikes in your performance when, for example, you are developing for mobile devices. In one hand it's not ideal (you want to keep at least 30fps) but the rule is avoid pre-optimization, so if you have spike you can address these one by one. So, having a garbage collector is not big obstacle, but sometimes you have to be careful with that.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard just for your information https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8543 low latency garbage collector could be (and we hope will be) implemented in the future. In case Julia and games, this link could be interesting too: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/11/05/go-julia-fourier-open-source-frequon-invaders